# T-SQL: sorting results by year, month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have the following statement:

```
select
    (datename(MM, SomeDate) + ' ' + datename(day, SomeDate)) as D,
    count(SomeID) as IDs
from dbo.SomeTable
where
    datename(MM, SomeDate) = @Month
    and datename(YYYY, SomeDate) = @Year
group by
    datename(YYYY, SomeDate),
    datename(MM, SomeDate),
    datename(DD, SomeDate);
```

It works but it sorts the result like this:

```
July 1, 2011 - 2
July 10, 2011 - 4
July 2, 2011 - 10
```

How do I make it to display July 10 after July 2? I know it's something simple but I can't find the problem. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Guys, I know there must be an "order by", I thought it's quite obvious. But the "normal" ordering produces the same result (see my comments). I think it's related to collation but I'm not an expert there.

Comment: Well, you've not requested any particular ordering in your query, so the system is free to return the results in any convenient order...

Comment: It doesn't change the order if I include "order by datename(YYYY, SomeDate), datename(MM, SomeDate), datename(DD, SomeDate)".

Comment: that's because you're converting valuable, rich, datetime information into strings, and then doing a string sort.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: so, what's the solution here?

Comment: @Kizz: add extra columns to sort on. As per his and my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing information from `somedate` *and* it isn't available for ORDER BY anyway

Sorting by DATENAME isn't what you want because July is after August

So, add more derived columns to the GROUP BY to sort on later that use DATEPART which gives numbers

```
select
    (datename(MM, SomeDate) + ' ' + datename(day, SomeDate)) as D,
    count(SomeID) as IDs
from
    dbo.SomeTable
where
    datename(MM, SomeDate) = @Month
    and datename(YYYY, SomeDate) = @Year
group by
    datename(YYYY, SomeDate),
    datename(MM, SomeDate),
    datename(DD, SomeDate),
    datepart(YYYY, SomeDate),
    datepart(MM, SomeDate),
    datepart(DD, SomeDate)
order by
    datepart(YYYY, SomeDate),
    datepart(MM, SomeDate),
    datepart(DD, SomeDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix it by moving the body of your query into a subquery, including `SomeDate` in the group by clause (having ensured to remove the time portion).

I'd personally avoid using `DateName` for this query - I'd rather use `DatePart` and keep everything numeric, but based on your query:

Setup:

```
create table SomeTable (
    SomeDate datetime not null,
    SomeID int not null
)
go
insert into SomeTable (SomeDate,SomeID)
select '20110701',1 union all
select '20110702',1 union all
select '20110710',1
```

Query:

```
declare @Month varchar(10)
declare @Year int
select @Month='July',@Year=2011

select D,IDs from (
select
    (datename(MM, SomeDate) + ' ' + datename(day, SomeDate)) as D,
    count(SomeID) as IDs
    ,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,SomeDate),0) as SomeDate
from dbo.SomeTable
where
    datename(MM, SomeDate) = @Month
    and datename(YYYY, SomeDate) = @Year
group by
    datename(YYYY, SomeDate),
    datename(MM, SomeDate),
    datename(DD, SomeDate),
    DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,SomeDate),0)
) t
order by SomeDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If `SomeDate` is of type `DATE` then you can simply add `ORDER BY SomeDate`. The `GROUP BY` can be simplified as well:

```
select
    (datename(MM, SomeDate) + ' ' + datename(day, SomeDate)) as D,
    count(SomeID) as IDs
from dbo.SomeTable
where
    datename(MM, SomeDate) = @Month
    and datename(YYYY, SomeDate) = @Year
group by
    SomeDate 
order by
    SomeDate ;
```

The `WHERE` can probably be simplified too.

---

If it's of type `DATETIME`, you can use:

```
select
    (datename(MM, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, SomeDate)))
      + ' ' + datename(day, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, SomeDate)))) as D,
    count(SomeID) as IDs
from dbo.SomeTable
where
    datename(MM, SomeDate) = @Month
    and datename(YYYY, SomeDate) = @Year
group by
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, SomeDate)) 
order by
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, SomeDate)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `ORDER BY` clause and order by `SomeDate`.

Comment: See comments to other answers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
   /*Event_type
   EventDate*/ AS EventCount
  ,MONTH(EventDate) AS MONTH
  ,YEAR(EventDate) AS YEAR
  ,DATENAME(MONTH ,EventDate) AS MonthName
FROM   EventTable
WHERE  (Event_type = 'TypeOfEvent')
   AND (Userid NOT LIKE '%*%')
GROUP BY
   YEAR(EventDate)
  ,MONTH(EventDate)
  ,DATENAME(MONTH ,EventDate)
ORDER BY
   YEAR
  ,MONTH
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.