# SQL get Month and Year name and order by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that pulls out the Month and amount. Like so:

```
Aug 2015    61.87
Dec 2015    10.83
Feb 2015    80.00
Jul 2015    56.19
Jun 2015    31.65
Mar 2015    59.02
May 2015    46.91
Nov 2015    6.00
Oct 2015    8.27
Sep 2015    15.73
```

As you can see the order is not correct. Here is my query

```
select 
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), InvoiceDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), InvoiceDate, 120)  as Month, 
  CONVERT(decimal(18,2), round(SUM(amount),2)) as Amount
from DataInvoice 
where Vendor='IceCreamTruck' 
  and AccountNumber = '54554' 
  and InvoiceDate >= '02/01/2015' 
  and InvoiceDate <= '01/31/2016' 
group by MONTH(InvoiceDate), 
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), InvoiceDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), InvoiceDate, 120)
```

I tried doing order by `Year()`, `Month()` but that did not work. It complains about is invalid in the `ORDER BY` clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Any idea on this? by the way the Invoice is in this formate YYYY-MM-DD

Thanks.

Comment: So InvoiceData is stored in the database as a string?

Comment: Why in the world would you do this in the SQL? Why wouldn't you do the formatting / casting in your programming language instead?

Comment: Maybe post your table schema...

Comment: Add actual columns for Year and Month (ordinal) - you can `ORDER BY` those without including them in the `SELECT`.

Comment: InvoiceDate is (Date, null)
Amount(decimal(22,6),null)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL: sorting results by year, month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642773/t-sql-sorting-results-by-year-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), InvoiceDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), InvoiceDate, 120),4)
         MONTH(InvoiceDate)
```

This essentially orders the results by year, then by month number, so it should give you the correct ordering.

Comment: When i do that i get the invalid in the ORDERBY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUPBY clause error again

Comment: Ahh That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot @Giorgos Betsos